# run py files in atom text editor like in cmd

Tags: python, atom-editor, idl

I am using atom editor. I installed atom runner for run to my programs but i have encountered too many problems. I want to run pyfiles in cmd console automaticly. How can i do this

In a nutshell:

```
How can i run py files in cmd console with shortcut
```

I am using windows

Comment: what operating system are you on? where are your files located? what do you mean by "with shortcut"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you install the "Script" extension and then run Atom using cmnd-I in the editor. Your file runs in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

This is honestly not related to stack overflow since this isn't exactly a computer programming question. More of an operating system question. However, I believe you can install bash (linux command line) on windows and this would help solve your problem. Here is a link: 
https://www.windowscentral.com/how-install-bash-shell-command-line-windows-10

OR if you prefer using the windows command line, this link can explain how to run python (although i'd recommend using bash and not cmd):
http://www.cs.bu.edu/courses/cs108/guides/runpython.html